# Magento Collection with nested "OR" "AND" Filter

Tags: magento-1.7

i am try to filter my collection which have nest "or" "and" filter 
where t_id & t_code both are attributes

```
     $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
                        array(
                            array(
                                'attribute' => 't_id',
                                'null' => true
                            ),

                                array(
                                    'attribute' => 't_id',
                                    'finset' => $allowedtId
                                )

                        )
                    );
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
                    array(
                        array(
                            'attribute' => 't_code',
                            'null' => true
                        ),
                        array(
                            'attribute' => 't_code',
                            'finset' => $tAttCode
                        )
                    )
                );
```

here is the sql of query

```
WHERE ((at_t_id.value IS NULL) OR (FIND_IN_SET('', at_t_id.value))) AND ((at_t_code.value IS NULL) OR (FIND_IN_SET('2348', at_t_code.value)))
```

but i am trying to get something like this

```
 WHERE (at_t_id.value IS NULL)

   OR 

 (
     (FIND_IN_SET('1245', at_t_id.value)) 

      AND

    (
        (at_t_code.value IS NULL)

         OR
        (FIND_IN_SET('2348', at_t_code.value))

    )
 )
```

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: Did you make any progress here?

Comment: @mpaepper not yet..if you have solution then plz help